# Why does intersection type for functions accept either of type declarations not both?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I took the example

```
/* @flow */
class Foo {}
class Bar {}
declare var f: ((x: Foo) => void) & ((x: Bar) => void);
f(new Foo());
```

from the documentation page https://flowtype.org/docs/union-intersection-types.html#_

And this code type checks without errors.

For me the result is not immediately obvious.

As they show somewhere near the top of the page with another example:

```
/* @flow */
type I = {a: number} & {b: number};
var x: I = {a: 1, b: 2};
x = {a: 1, b: 2, c: "three"};
```

the intersection (which flows from the term semantics itself) is the compound of 2 (or more) types. Basically `AND` of those.

So, why does the `f(new Foo());` not fail the type check then? The `new Foo()` argument is clearly not an instance of the `Bar` so must not pass.

What am I missing?

**UPD**

After some more research I have found that the meaning of `|` and `&` swaps when you use `declare var` (versus `type` or in-place typing). I cannot find an explanation why it even happens in the very first place though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but I would expect it to typecheck. The argument, `new Foo()`, has type `Foo`, so the application should be ok as long as `f` has type `Foo => ...`. It does. (It *also* has type `Bar => ...`).

For comparison, if `f` had type `(x: Foo & Bar) => void`, things wouldn't typecheck, because `new Foo`, while certainly of type `Foo`, is not also of type `Bar`.

For another comparison, if `f` had type `((x: Foo) => void) | ((x: Bar) => void)`, things wouldn't typecheck. The argument, `new Foo`, has type `Foo`, and although `f` might have type `Foo => void`, it might instead have type `Bar => void`.

Comment: I would just quote the documentation: "An intersection type requires a value to be all of the input types:". In this example the argument DOES NOT satisfy this, since the `f(new Foo());` is not of the `((x: Bar) => void)` type.

Comment: Another controversial example: `declare var` and `declare type` behave differently: https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAxjAhgZx2AMTjjAG8BfDbPMAISwCczKATAU00bbABcBPAA7cCYALxgAFBIAeALkLEAlGIB8YAG5wAli2UAySTPn0Gy0Ws07FAblSp1jMFjDyR4qAFcAduh5a4XjIuCnDKFKhYEl5sSERwEoo2QA

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite following: the `(x: Bar) => void` type is for `f` itself, not `f(new Foo())`. We're saying that the `f` function is both of type `(x: Foo) => void` as well as of type `(x: Bar) => void`; as such, it's fine to call it on an argument of type `Foo`.

Comment: In your try flow example, the issue is that you've said `a` has type `F = ((x: Foo) => void) & ((x: Bar) => void)`, but it doesn't! It only has type `(x: Foo) => void`. If you change the definition of `a` to `function(x: Foo | Bar)`, though, it will typecheck again.

Comment: Now I see what you mean, but it's still counter intuitive for me :-S

Comment: Cool, glad I could help :)